# Access personal views in a list with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to first access and then edit Personal Views for a SharePoint List using PowerShell. However only the public views are returned. In the example below the list called List1 has two views - 1 public and 1 personal created by a regular user account (contoso\user1).

I run the script below via an admin account (contoso\spadmin) -

```
$url= "http://portal.contoso.com/sites/TEST"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists["List1"]
Write-Output "Count = $($list.views.count)"
$list.views| % {Write-Output "Title = $($_.title)"}
```

Result -

```
Count = 1
Title = All Items
```

I tried the following as well but that did not return the personal views.

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{ 
    $web = Get-SPWeb $url
    $list = $web.Lists["List1"]
    Write-Host "Count = $($list.views.count)"
    $list.views| % {Write-Host "Title = $($_.title)"}
}
)
```

How do I access the personal views for a list with PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the user's personal view you need to create the SPSite object with that particular user's Token.

Below is the sample code which shows how to access the personal views in C# code. You can create equivalent powershell code. This code gives you idea how to get the personal views.

```
static void GetViews(SPSite site)
        {
            SPWeb spweb = site.OpenWeb();
            foreach(SPUser oUser in spweb.AllUsers)
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SPSite oElevSite = new SPSite(site.ID, oUser.UserToken);
                        SPWeb oElevWeb = oElevSite.RootWeb;
                        SPList splist = oElevWeb.Lists["CustomStatusList"];
                        SPViewCollection views = splist.Views;
                        foreach (SPView view in views)
                        {
                            if (view.PersonalView)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(oUser.Name +":"+ view.Title);
                            }
                        }
                        oElevWeb.Dispose();
                        oElevSite.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

In powershell you can use usertoken as:

```
$user=$web.AllUsers.GetByID(1073741823)

$token = $user.UserToken;

$impWebObj= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($web.Url, $token);
```

Comment: Ok, i will try this but what is your code doing when it creates a site object with user.UserToken and that too for each user? My user id already has admin rights and when I call RunWithElevatedPrivileges in my script it runs in the web app pool account which also has rights to the DB.

Comment: Actually when site object is created with user object it will give personal view for that particular user. If you run your code with RunWithElevatedPrivileges, it will give you personal view for admin your.

Comment: Is this something like impersonating twice? RunWithElevatedPrivileges runs as the app pool and then creating a site using the usertoken impersonates the user. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. this is how you will get all personal views.

Comment: Thanks! So that was the missing piece. I am able to get the views. Do you have any idea why Write-Output does NOT work when using RunWithElevatedPrivileges? Only write-host works.